# Method for drawing vector graphics

Tags: javascript, webgl, electron, vector-graphics

I am trying to draw some vector graphics and I found two ways:

(I have to mention that I use electron width nodejs and therefore the language is javascript and instead of OpenGL there is WebGL.)

- Triangulate the shapes and draw it with WebGL. I think this is a fast method. But my concern is when you are moving single points, the shape has to retriangulated. And I don't know how fast this can be done.
- Calcualate on a per pixel basis with inside/outside equations on the CPU. But after every resizing or moving the changed pixels has to be recalculated.

Can somebody give me any hints or some experience someone already has made?
Also how are Illustrator, Inkscape, etc. rendering their graphics?

Thank you

Comment: [Why not use svg directly ?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web)

Comment: Yes. I thought about that already. But it seems that it is really slow with multiple svg's. Also I don't have much control about the rendering.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. "draw some vector graphics" = what? A bar graph? A world map? A ridiculously complex adobe illustrator creation? As for calculate inside/outside, [you can do that on the GPU as well](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html). On top of that if you really wanted to get crazy you could use emscripten to compile all of [Skia](https://skia.org/) and given that WebAssembly is supposed to be 1.5x the speed to native assembly whatever you're trying to solve isn't likely to be limited by WebGL or JavaScript

Comment: I should also mentioned i agree with LJ. Why not just use SVG? Illustrator itself gets slow that's why there's a wireframe mode.

Comment: @gman: thanks for your comment. I want to draw some complex shapes. One or morge points of this shapes are often moved. Also I want to do some boolean operations. I think when I often change the svg data it gets really slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several ways to draw vector graphics on Web Platform.

Frist one, as mentioned in comments, SVG. It's perfectly fine if your graphics are mainly static or aren't extensively updated. For example, our Maps API uses SVG in some cases and it's sufficiently performant. And it's substantially easier to use that other options.

The second one is, of course, [Canvas2D API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D). For the most, it's just an API to browsers painting backend (e.g., [Skia](https://skia.org) for Chrome). The very same backend is used for everything else: HTML, SVG, sometimes even GUI. However, it gives our a bit more control over the rendering. And if your scene is heavily animated and/or needs to be highly interactive, there's good chance you'll be able to make a much more performant rendering that SVG. That's due to ability to make lightweight, highly specialised and thus faster renderer. But there're some catches. Most important would be necessity to implement your own hit test to provide some interactivity for your scene (SVG provider an event model).

If even Canvas2D isn't enough for you, there's a third way and it's WebGL. If used right it should be the most performant one. It provides you most control over resources and rendering itself and it's almost always fully hardware accelerated. But achieving that performance may be a challenge. But there're libraries out there which provides Canvas2D-like API, but powered by WebGL, for example [Pixi.js](http://www.pixijs.com).

About the last part of your question. I don't know about Adobe Illustrator, but Inkscape [uses](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk/view/head:/src/display/drawing-context.h#L129) [Cairo](https://www.cairographics.org), as, actually, many applications, including Mozilla Firefox. In its turn Cairo can use one of multiple crossplatform or platform specific [backends](https://www.cairographics.org/backends/).